# Get data from all tables in database

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have 5 tables in my database they are as follows
officelocations_tbl
state_tbl
city_tbl
staff_tbl
titles_tbl

The titles table is only associated with the staff table but the others are all inner joined. I have tried various mysql statements but none are allowing me to bring in the titles_tbl. 
here is the latest version of the sql statement I am attempting to use:

```
    SELECT officelocations_tbl.*,city_tbl.*, state_tbl.* , titles_tbl.*, 
    contact1.firstName AS c1Firstname, contact1.lastName AS c1lastName, 
    contact1.middleInitial AS c1middleInitial, contact1.suffix AS c1suffix, 
    contact1.accredations AS c1accredations, contact1.phone AS c1Phone, 
    contact1.faxNumber AS c1FaxNumber, contact1.mobilePhone AS c1Mobile, 
    contact1.email AS c1Email, contact1.titleID AS c1Title, 

    contact2.firstName AS c2Firstname, contact2.lastName AS c2lastName, 
    contact2.middleInitial AS c2middleInitial, contact2.suffix AS c2suffix, 
    contact2.accredations AS c2accredations,  contact2.phone AS c2Phone, 
    contact2.faxNumber AS c2FaxNumber, contact2.mobilePhone AS c2Mobile, 
    contact2.email AS c2Email, contact2.titleID AS c2Title, 

    partner.firstName AS c3Firstname, partner.lastName AS c3lastName, 
    partner.middleInitial AS c3middleInitial, partner.suffix AS c3suffix, 
    partner.accredations AS c3accredations, partner.phone AS c3Phone, 
    partner.faxNumber AS c3FaxNumber, partner.mobilePhone AS c3Mobile, 
    partner.email AS c3Email, partner.titleID AS c3Title 

    FROM officelocations_tbl 

    JOIN city_tbl ON (officelocations_tbl.cityID = city_tbl.cityID)  
    INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN state_tbl ON (officelocations_tbl.stateID = state_tbl.stateID) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact1 ON (contact1.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact2 ON (contact2.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact2) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl partner ON (partner.staffID = officelocations_tbl.partner)
```

However this gives me an error [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'staff_tbl.titleID' in 'on clause'. If I remove both the lines:

```
    INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID
    titles_tbl.*,
```

it works but doesn't pull in the title. I have tried doing it this way as well but then it only pulls in the title once and not for all three contacts.

```
    SELECT
    staff_tbl.staffID,
    staff_tbl.staffID_C2,
    staff_tbl.staffID_P,
    staff_tbl.firstName,
    staff_tbl.middleInitial,
    staff_tbl.lastName,
    staff_tbl.suffix,
    staff_tbl.accredations,
    staff_tbl.email,
    staff_tbl.phone,
    staff_tbl.mobilePhone,
    staff_tbl.officePhone,
    staff_tbl.faxNumber,
    staff_tbl.address1,
    staff_tbl.address2,
    staff_tbl.cityID,
    staff_tbl.stateID,
    staff_tbl.zipCode,
    staff_tbl.titleID,
    staff_tbl.locationID,
    staff_tbl.photoURL,
    staff_tbl.vCardURL,
    staff_tbl.qRCodeURL,
    staff_tbl.resumeURL,
    staff_tbl.biography,
    staff_tbl.dateCreated,
    officelocations_tbl.locationID,
    officelocations_tbl.officeName,
    officelocations_tbl.address1,
    officelocations_tbl.address2,
    officelocations_tbl.cityID,
    officelocations_tbl.stateID,
    officelocations_tbl.zipCode,
    officelocations_tbl.officePhone,
    officelocations_tbl.contact1,
    officelocations_tbl.contact2,
    officelocations_tbl.partner,
    city_tbl.cityID,
    city_tbl.cityName,
    state_tbl.stateID,
    state_tbl.state_abreviation,
    state_tbl.state_name,
    titles_tbl.titleID,
    titles_tbl.titleName, 

    contact1.firstName AS c1Firstname, contact1.lastName AS c1lastName, 
    contact1.middleInitial AS c1middleInitial, contact1.suffix AS c1suffix, 
    contact1.accredations AS c1accredations, contact1.phone AS c1Phone, 
    contact1.faxNumber AS c1FaxNumber, contact1.mobilePhone AS c1Mobile, 
    contact1.email AS c1Email, contact1.titleID AS c1Title, 

    contact2.firstName AS c2Firstname, contact2.lastName AS c2lastName, 
    contact2.middleInitial AS c2middleInitial, contact2.suffix AS c2suffix, 
    contact2.accredations AS c2accredations, contact2.phone AS c2Phone, 
    contact2.faxNumber AS c2FaxNumber, contact2.mobilePhone AS c2Mobile, 
    contact2.email AS c2Email, contact2.titleID AS c2Title, 

    partner.firstName AS c3Firstname, partner.lastName AS c3lastName, 
    partner.middleInitial AS c3middleInitial, partner.suffix AS c3suffix, 
    partner.accredations AS c3accredations, partner.phone AS c3Phone, 
    partner.faxNumber AS c3FaxNumber, partner.mobilePhone AS c3Mobile, 
    partner.email AS c3Email, partner.titleID AS c3Title 

    FROM officelocations_tbl
    INNER JOIN staff_tbl ON staff_tbl.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1
    INNER JOIN state_tbl ON state_tbl.stateID = officelocations_tbl.stateID
    INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID
    INNER JOIN city_tbl ON city_tbl.cityID = officelocations_tbl.cityID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact1 ON (contact1.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl contact2 ON (contact2.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact2) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_tbl partner ON (partner.staffID = officelocations_tbl.partner)
```

This will only pull for the first association of staff_tbl.staffID = officelocations_tbl.contact1. I am stumped as to what to try next. Is there anyone who would know how to get it to pull all 5 tables?

Comment: It might be a dumb question, but are you sure that the staff_tbl contains the column titleID ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your INNER JOIN down lower, e.g. from

```
INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN state_tbl ON (officelocations_tbl.stateID = state_tbl.stateID)
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN state_tbl ON (officelocations_tbl.stateID = state_tbl.stateID) 
INNER JOIN titles_tbl ON titles_tbl.titleID = staff_tbl.titleID
```

At the time the parser reaches the INNER JOIN, staff_tbl has not yet been joined, and the parser will not "look ahead" to see if it's joined later. So it immediately bails with a "no such table/field".

Switching the order in which this occurs allows taff_table to be joined in first, and then you can use it in further joins.

Comment: Still get same error message as before [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'staff_tbl.titleID' in 'on clause'. If I remove that inner join along with the select of all the information in the titles table it works but doesn't pull the titles only the title ids.

Comment: Oops, should have another left join in this part. one sec to edit the answer... and just noticed that you're aliasing the staff_tbl away to all kinds of different names, never leaving an actual "staff_tbl" available. yet another join on staff_tbl, with *NO* alias would help.

Comment: not sure I can do that. I tried once but the issue would be that I have only one spot in the staff table for staff_ID and 3 different spots in the locations_tbl one for contact1, contact2 and partner. It errors out when I try to link the 1 staff_ID to 3 different spots in the locations_tbl.